# Multiple Dropzone fileuploads in Google Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to upload a file via Google Puppeteer on a page with multiple (three) Dropzone instances.

The first instance accepts video files, while the other two accept image types.

To upload a file to the video Dropzone I'm using this code which is working fine:

```js
const fileSelector = '.dz-hidden-input[type=file][accept*=mp4]';
const element = await page.waitForSelector(fileSelector);
await element.uploadFile('/path/to/file.mp4');
```

Now I try to identify the other two image instance file inputs. To get the file input DOM handles I can use this:

```
const dropzone1 = await page.$eval('#image-dropzone-1', dz => dz.dropzone.hiddenFileInput);`
```

As this is returning a DOM handle `dropzone1.uploadFile()` is not available. Seems I need to have a `elementHandle` to use this function.

I'd like to avoid using a selector like this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.dz-hidden-input[type=file][accept*=jpg]:nth-of-type(2)')`as it's not very stable.
```

Does anyone know how I can identify the fields accordingly? As the hidden file inputs don't have any unique attributes.

Comment: What do you mean "as it's not very stable" for the last selector?

Comment: It's a 3rd party website so they might change the markup/order of the inputs which would break the script.

Comment: Isn't that how scraping works? You automate others website but what they do with their own website should also mean you need to update your script.

Comment: I agree completely. Sure I can do it the "unstable" way, but still want to know how (or if) this can be achieved in Puppeteer.